# Force order on forms access in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two forms for registration. I am saving the first form data in session. The problem is the user can access the second form without filling in the first form.

I want to restrict the user from accessing the second form directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in second form  that data in session are available or not. If not available then you can redirect him to first form

If you have any query fill free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is that a user cant acces the form, if there is no session? Correct? Cause if so, its a matter of making an if-else statement.

What i do is when i create the session, i make a session variable, for instance with, for instance the username. Then you retrieve that data on the next page in the second form

```
$UserName = $_SESSION['Username'];
```

And then you run an if else statement

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username']) || $_SESSION['Username'] == '')
{ echo "ERROR STATEMENT or Redirect back to first form";}
else
{ echo "your second form";}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This. Except he should be using cake methods instead of accessing directly the $_SESSION var. `if ($this->Session->read('Username')){ ...;}`

Comment: Read the php tag, forgot to check further on the cakephp tag, my mistake. However, the method indeed is the same, just a different syntax.